# Is it possible to implement a method that clones an object and applies changes to private properties (without reflection)?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Value objects in DDD are immutable, the properties are typically set once via the constructor.

I sometimes require a copy of a value object with only some changes, e.g. ten of the properties should be copied and one property will get a new value. In this case I want to avoid using a constructor with eleven parameters, instead I want to implement a method that returns a copy but at the same time applies some changes to the properties. I know I can do this via reflection but would like to check if it is possible to avoid reflection.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; } // actual use case is { get; private set; }
    
    public Foo(int bar)
    {
        Bar = bar;
    }
    
    public Foo CloneAndApply(Action<Foo> apply)
    {
        var result = new Foo(Bar);
        apply(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

This works because the "Bar" property has a public setter. I require something that allows setting "Bar" when it is a private member.

```
var test = new Foo(1);
var clone = test.CloneAndApply(x => x.Bar = 2);
Console.WriteLine(clone.Bar);
```

Comment: Would `public Foo CloneAndApply(int bar)` not work? I know that your example is most likely a simplified version of what you need, but maybe you just need few different constructors?

Comment: @tymtam Yes that would work but leaves me with an ugly amount of parameters for CloneAndApply when I am using many properties - plus I will have to change the signature every time a property will be added or removed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in [Records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9), introduced in C# 9. Records contain many parts, but one of them is support for "[withers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression)", which interact with the new init-only properties to easily let you create modified copies of records.

Records support things like primary constructors, which I'm going to gloss over here. At a simple level, your record might look like:

```
public record Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; init; }
    
    public Foo(int bar)
    {
        Bar = bar;
    }
}
```

and could be used as:

```
var foo = new Foo(3);
var foo2 = foo with { Bar = 4 };
```

This record also automatically implements equality, based on the equality of its individual members, and an overridded `ToString` implementation.

The long-term plan is to allow withers to be used with non-record types, although (as of C# 9) this is not yet supported.

---

If you take advantage of primary constructors, you can write your record even more concisely:

```
public record Foo(int Bar);
```

This auto-generates the `Bar` property, with `get` and `init` accessors, and a constructor which assigns to it.

Comment: Beautiful, one reason to start using .NET 5 - too bad I am currently stuck with Core 3.1. I think this is the answer though, since there is probably no way to do this without reflection and  C# < 9

Comment: You can use this on .NET Core 3.1, as long as you're using the .NET 5 SDK, and set `<LangVersion>9</LangVersion>` in your csproj. You'll also need `namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices { internal static class IsExternalInit { } }` somewhere in your project.

Comment: Good to know - I work in a team and this is not an ad hoc change I can make, but it looks like the impact is controllable

Answer (score 3):

I achieve this pre .net5's records with `WithX` methods that pass the property that needs to be different. It's not fancy but it works.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int X { get; private set; }
    
    public int Bar { get; private set; }
    
    public Foo(int x, int bar) { X = x; Bar = bar; }
    
    public Foo WithBar(int bar) => new Foo(X, bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what Roslyn does, FWIW

Answer (score 1):

Another solution might be reflection. This can also be used to assign values to private properties:

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Foo(1);
            var clone = test.CloneAndApply(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("Bar").SetValue(x, 2));
            Console.WriteLine(clone.Bar);
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public int Bar { get; private set; }

        public Foo(int bar)
        {
            Bar = bar;
        }

        public Foo CloneAndApply(Action<Foo> apply)
        {
            var result = new Foo(Bar);
            apply(result);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not what I am looking for since it uses reflection, still a good example on how to do it with reflection

Comment: @TvdH Ah, I see. Sorry. Just out of interest, why without Reflection? Is there any specific reason?